# get last messageId of a each room using join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, join

hi i want to get a last msg of each room with respect to time, below is my table
cmUserRegistration is used for registration,cmUserFriendProfiles for friends details,cmChatRooms chat room for 2 users,cmChatRoomMessages for storing messages.

this is my query,

```
SELECT 
    cmUserFriendProfiles.friendOf,
    cmUserFriendProfiles.friendId,

    cmUserRegistration.userId AS userid,
    cmUserRegistration.firstName AS userfirstname,
    cmUserRegistration.lastName AS userlastname,
    cmUserRegistration.statusTagLine AS usertagline,
    cmUserRegistration.profilePicUrl AS userprofilepic,
    cmChatRooms.roomId AS chatroomid,
    cmChatRoomMessages.createdTimeStamp,
    cmChatRoomMessages.messageId

    FROM  
        cmUserRegistration 
    INNER JOIN
        cmUserFriendProfiles 
        ON 
        cmUserRegistration.userId=cmUserFriendProfiles.friendId
    INNER JOIN
        cmChatRooms 
        ON
        (cmChatRooms.participant1=cmUserRegistration.userId OR cmChatRooms.participant2=cmUserRegistration.userId)
    LEFT JOIN
        cmChatRoomMessages 
        ON 
        cmChatRoomMessages.roomId=cmChatRooms.roomId


    WHERE 
        cmUserFriendProfiles.friendOf=_selfid 
        AND 
        cmChatRooms.roomType='public';
```

out put of above code

```
[{"friendOf":2,"friendId":12,"userid":12,"chatroomid":1,"createdTimeStamp":null,"messageId":null},{"friendOf":2,"friendId":3,"userid":3,"chatroomid":2,"createdTimeStamp":null,"messageId":null},{"friendOf":2,"friendId":4,"userid":4,"chatroomid":3,"createdTimeStamp":"**2014-04-15T06:00:50.000**Z","messageId":8},{"friendOf":2,"friendId":4,"userid":4,"chatroomid":3,"createdTimeStamp":"**2014-04-15T06:09:54.000**Z","messageId":6}]
```

in the output i want only last inserted messageid of each room, here i am getting all messagesid for that room,

here below i tried this

```
SELECT 
    cmUserFriendProfiles.friendOf,
    cmUserFriendProfiles.friendId,

    cmUserRegistration.userId AS userid,
    cmChatRooms.roomId AS chatroomid,
    cmChatRoomMessages.createdTimeStamp,
    cmChatRoomMessages.messageId

    FROM  
        cmUserRegistration 
    INNER JOIN
        cmUserFriendProfiles 
        ON 
        cmUserRegistration.userId=cmUserFriendProfiles.friendId
    INNER JOIN
        cmChatRooms 
        ON
        (cmChatRooms.participant1=cmUserRegistration.userId OR cmChatRooms.participant2=cmUserRegistration.userId)
    LEFT JOIN
        cmChatRoomMessages 
        ON 
        cmChatRoomMessages.roomId=cmChatRooms.roomId
    LEFT join
        (SELECT messageId, MAX(createdTimeStamp) maxdate FROM cmChatRoomMessages)temp
        ON
        (cmChatRoomMessages.createdTimeStamp=maxdate)

    WHERE 
        cmUserFriendProfiles.friendOf=_selfid 
        AND 
        cmChatRooms.roomType='public';
```

but still the same output, where i am going wrong, please correct me, any help will b appreciated, thank you

Comment: You have no GROUP BY clause

Comment: where to use group by , i tried on with this LEFT join
        (SELECT messageId, MAX(createdTimeStamp) maxdate FROM cmChatRoomMessages group by cmChatRoomMessages.roomId)temp
        ON
        (cmChatRoomMessages.createdTimeStamp=maxdate) but no use

Comment: You're selecting the messageid and grouping by the roomid. Does that make sense to you? If you're still struggling, I suggest you cut this query back to the bare bones of the problem, and provide a sqlfiddle of representative data TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: ooo srry, group by cmChatRoomMessages.messageId, but the same result